# What is the general purpose of using hashtables as a collection?

Tags: java, hashtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly are hashtables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625168/what-exactly-are-hashtables)

I understand the purpose of using hash functions to securely store passwords. I have used arrays and arraylists for class projects for sorting and searching data. What I am having trouble understanding is the practical value of hashtables for something like sorting and searching.

I got a lecture on hashtables but we never had to use them in school, so it hasn't clicked. Can someone give me a practical example of a task a hashtable is useful for that couldn't be done with a numerical array or arraylist? Also, a very simple low level example of a hash function would be helpful.

Comment: I have voted to close, as this question is an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625168/what-exactly-are-hashtables . You should be aware that 'hash' and 'hash table' are very different things. A hash table uses a hash function in its operation, but hash functions are used for other purposes too.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @Joe hashes may have other uses, but I sure hope `public int hashCode()` has one purpose: for placement into hashtables.

Comment: Absolutely! But I don't think the asker was asking about the hashcode method, they did mention 'hash functions' in the context of passwords etc.

Comment: @Joe: OP said he understands why we use hash functions for passwords, but asks why they are used for implementing collections and/or what these collections are for. And why is this tagged `functional-programming`? You can't even implement one (efficiently) in purely functional languages and even in the not-quite-pure ones, trees are usually treated equally or preferred.

Comment: Agreed! I have removed the FP tag. I made my comments based on the assumption that he was conflating the two terms. Anyway, there are plenty of good answers on the duplicate question (and some good ones here, for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, hashtables have similar performance characteristics (cheap lookup, cheap appending (for arrays - hashtables are unordered, adding to them is cheap partly because of this) as arrays with numerical indices, but are much more flexible in terms of what the key may be. Given a continuous chunck of memory and a fixed size per item, you can get the adress of the `n`th item very easily and cheaply. That's thanks to the indices being integers - you can't do that with, say, strings. At least not directly. Hashes allows reducing any object (that implements it) to a number and you're back to arrays. You still need to add checks for hash collisions and resolve them (which incurs mostly a memory overhead, since you need to store the original value), but with a halfway decent implementation, this is not much of an issue.

So you can now associate *any* (hashable) object with *any* (really any) value. This has countless uses (although I have to admit, I can't think of one that's applyable to sorting or searching). You can build caches with small overhead (because checking if the cache can help in a given case is O(1)), implement a relatively performant object system (several dynamic languages do this), you can go through a list of `(id, value)` pairs and accumulate the values for identical `id`s in any way you like, and many other things.

Answer (score 2):

There are all sorts of collections out there. Collections are used for storing and retrieving things, so one of the most important properties of a collection is how fast these operations are. To estimate "fastness" people in computer science use big-O notation which sort of means how many individual operations you have to accomplish to invoke a certain method (be it get or set for example). So for example to get an element of an ArrayList by an index you need exactly 1 operation, this is O(1), if you have a LinkedList of length n and you need to get something from the middle, you'll have to traverse from the start of the list to the middle, taking n/2 operations, in this case get has complexity of O(n). The same comes to key-value stores as hastable. There are implementations that give you complexity of O(log n) to get a value by its key whereas hastable copes in O(1). Basically it means that getting a value from hashtable by its key is really cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Hashtables are often called "associated arrays." Arrays allow access your data by index. Hash tables allow access your data by any other identifier, e.g. name. For example
one is associated with 1
two is associated with 2

So, when you got word "one" you can find its value 1 using hastable where key is one and value is 1. Array allows only opposite mapping.

Comment: Ok I understand associative arrays I didn't realize they were the same as hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

For n data elements:

Hashtables allows O(k) (usually dependent only on the hashing function) searches. This is better than O(log n) for binary searches (which follow an n log n sorting, if data is not sorted you are worse off)

However, on the flip side, the hashtables tend to take roughly 3n amount of space.